# Changing the position of submit button (windows wrap credential provider )

Tags: c++, windows-7, credential-providers

I have been recently working on customizing windows wrap credential provider.Added secondary password field(OTP) but problem arise as i am unable to adjust the position of submit button.i have tried couple of thing but have failed

Here is the login interface of the wrap credential provider
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aL6Do.png)

Here is the function of the submit button

```
HRESULT CSampleCredential::GetSubmitButtonValue(
DWORD dwFieldID,
DWORD* pdwAdjacentTo
)

{
 HRESULT hr = E_UNEXPECTED;
    if (_pWrappedCredential != NULL)
      { 
           hr = _pWrappedCredential->GetSubmitButtonValue(dwFieldID, 
             pdwAdjacentTo);
       }
                  return hr;
  }
```

The new password field that is OTP field is named as "SFI_PASSWORD"
and the submit button field needs to be adjacent to this field.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be I am answering this too late but could be of some help to others. You need to set the index of the field that submit button should be placed adjacent to, for example if you want the submit button to be adjacent to the password input field it should be `*pdwAdjacentTo = SFI_PASSWORD;`. In your case I think you need to give index of that one time password input field.

[image]